# Eclipse e4 image icons for widgets and how to keep them handy

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

I was wondering does eclipse e4 come with some image icons already offered to use in various swt widgets (buttons, labels etc)?
If not:
Is there a place I could find icons offered?
What is the standard practice in eclipse e4 development? I.e. I would prefer the icons I gather to somehow be centrally available to all my projects. Is this possible or my only option would be to just save all in a central file in the file system?

**Update:**
I found this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=148108/) that says there are some standard icons in `org.eclipse.ui.jar`
Any idea how would I use this for my application?

Answer (score 1):

Benjamion Cabé has posted a way to get all the Eclipse icons. See his [blog post here](http://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2009/06/02/icones-eclipse).
The link to the resulting icons zip file is dead but I guess the script may still work.